How to write out all connected devices using Libparted on Linux Mint?
I have been trying to print out all connected storage devices to my machine using C++ and libparted on Linux Mint 22 x86_64.
I have been tinkering with the ped_device_get_next() function, that should return the next device in the list provided by the ped_device_probe_all() function. I have trouble getting this to work, since the documentation on this library is pretty poor.
The most useful thing I've gotten to work is this simple chunk of code.
#include <cmakeconfig.h>
#include "mainheader.h"

int main()
{
    ped_device_probe_all();

    PedDevice *tempbed;
    int c = 0;
    do {
        tempbed = ped_device_get_next(NULL);
        std::cout<<c<<" "<<tempbed->model<<"\n";
        c++;
    } while(tempbed != NULL && c < 256); 

    return 0;
}

And all it does is print out the model of my SSD 256 times. Without the c variable acting as a safety mechanism, it does it forever (until the resources run out I guess).
It does not print out the model of my HDD anywhere.
I know that my code does exactly what the documentation says, prints out the first device x times, but I just cannot figure out how to make it print out the devices consecutively.
0 <model name>
1 <model name>
2 <model name>
3 <model name>
4 <model name>
etc.

Documentation of ped_device_get_next

"...since the documentation on this library is pretty poor." -- please do file tickets, with explanations what is unclear and, if you can, suggestions to improve this. Since the authors are familiar with the code, they can easily become kind-of blind to the needs of outside users.

@UlrichEckhardt Will do!

You initially call ped_device_get_next(NULL); Then on subsequent calls, you pass the value it returned on the previous call. One way to do this would be something like this:
int main()
{
    ped_device_probe_all();

    PedDevice *tempbed = nullptr;
    int c = 0;

    while((tempbed = ped_device_get_next(tempbed))!= nullptr && c <255) {
        std::cout<<c<<" "<<tempbed->model<<"\n";
        c++;
    } 

    return 0;
}

...or you could wrap it up onto a class that imitates a container:
#include <parted/parted.h>


class devices {
public:
    class iterator {
        PedDevice *current = nullptr;
    public:
        iterator &operator++() {
            current = ped_device_get_next(current);
            return *this;
        }

        PedDevice &operator*() const { return *current; }

        bool operator!=(iterator const &other) const { 
            return current != other.current;
        }
    };
    
    devices() { ped_device_probe_all(); }
    iterator begin() {
        iterator i;
        return ++i;        
    }
    iterator end() { return iterator(); }
};

...then iterate over it like almost a other container:
int main()
{
    devices dev;

    for (auto const &d : dev) {
        std::cout << d.model << "\n";
    }
}

As an aside, note that on most systems, you'll have to run this as root for it to actually show anything.

This solution works, thank you.
Yep, without running as root the program returned Segmentation Fault.

@HubertGonera: Yeah--as it stands, it has no error checking...
